# Is it possible to create a python dash component out of sprotty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly-dash

To preface this, I am very new to javascript and anything related. I want to use plotly's dash library to create a component that displays a graph laid out by ELK and rendered by sprotty. I haven't been able to find any tutorials of this online or any examples to learn off of, so if anyone knows if it's possible please tell me. Any advice is appreciated.

From my understanding, the thing needs to be wrapped into some class with the following structure in order for the dash component boilerplate to create a dash component

```
class myComponent extends Component {
    /* constructor, and any relevant functions */
    render () {
        return (
            /* some JSX */
        );
    }
}
```

Every example of sprotty code I've seen is run through an HTML `<script>` tag.